# Discord.py - Deposit command in Economy System Bot doesn't work properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i coded an Economy System bot, that should be able to subtract Money from the wallet and put it into the bank. But every time i try to execute the commands "deposit" and "withdraw" like it should be executed (When i execute it in a wrong way it sends the Messages it's supposed to send in this case). I suspect, that the Problem is the if statement "if amount>bal[0]", but i don't know. Anyways, Here's my Code and the Error it gives out, when i try to execute "deposit" and "withdraw" (I'll just post the deposit command here, because withdraw and deposit are almost equal):

```py
async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)
    return users


async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] =+ change
    with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"],users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
    return user


@client.command()
async def deposit(ctx,amount = None):
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Bitte gebe den Betrag an!")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[0]:
        await ctx.send("Du hast nicht genug Geld!")

    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send("Der Betrag muss eine positive Zahl sein!")
        return

    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1* amount)
    await update_bank(ctx.author, amount, "bank")

    await ctx.send(f"Du hast {amount} Moneten auf deine Bank gelegt")
```

Here's the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an Exception: 
TypeError: 'Member' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Can you please add the error? And the `update_bank` function?

Comment: Edited it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten to open the account at the beginning of your `deposit` command.

```py
    async def deposit(ctx, amount=None):
        await open_account(ctx.author)
```

You also forgot to add a `return` after `if amount > bal[0]:`.

```py
        if amount > bal[0]:
            await ctx.send("**You do not have enough money to do this!**")
            return
```

Also your `update_bank` seems to have a mistake. You need to return `bal` at the end, not `user`. In your case:

```py
async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

users[str(user.id)][mode] =+ change
with open ("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"],users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
return bal
```

Comment: Now it actually deposits something onto the bank account but instead of subtracting it from the walet it just multiplies the wallet by -1

Comment: Your `open_account` function please. Please watch the video carefully...

Comment: I know the video you are watching. I rebuilt the system 1:1 and everything works fine. Please be aware that typos or wrong indentations can cause those errors. I would advise you to look at the video again.